# IOS and shoutcast

Tags: objective-c, ios, shoutcast

I'd like to know how to get the stream from a shoutcast radio and manage it with a native iphone app.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage it"?

Comment: Be able to Listen at it by the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats overviewed here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

"I present a sample application that streams and plays an audio file from a URL on the iPhone or Mac."